# Adding sentence breaks to the beginning and end of each element in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list-comprehension, map-function

I have a list of strings:

`mini_corpus = ['I am Sam','Sam I am','I am Sam','I do not like green eggs and Sam']`

I need to add a sentence boundary at the beginning and end of each element (i.e. 'BOS I am Sam EOS', 'BOS Sam I am EOS', etc.)

I've tried using map : `mini_corpv2 = list(map(lambda x: 'BOS{}EOS'.format(x), mini_corpus))` but it throws `'list' object is not callable`

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong or suggest another method to implement this?

Comment: Your exact code works fine for me. Just add spaces `'BOS {} EOS'`, you can use a list-comprehension too `['BOS {} EOS'.format(x) for x in mini_corpus]`

Comment: Do you have any variables named `list` in the rest of your code? If so, try renaming that as it overrides the default list implementation in python.

Comment: Thanks, turns out I just needed to re-run the kernel

Comment: @azro Or they could drop the pointless lambda: `list(map('BOS {} EOS'.format, mini_corpus))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose the problem is somewhere else. Your code runs without problems, resulting in

```
['BOSI am SamEOS',
 'BOSSam I amEOS',
 'BOSI am SamEOS',
 'BOSI do not like green eggs and SamEOS']
```

(so you will probably want to add spaces after BOS and before EOS).

An alternative solution using list comprehension:

```
mini_corpv2 = [f'BOS {x} EOS' for x in mini_corpus]
```